# Sequence of Patterns within Date/time range

Tags: sql, hive

I have a problem I would need help on ..

In the example below, if I want to get scenarios based on the data patterns 010 as scenario1, 000 as scenario2, 111 as scenario3 within the Id.. Ignore the records that doesn't follow the pattern..

Ex:

```
id  date        Status
1   2012-10-18  1
1   2012-10-19  1
1   2012-10-20  0
1   2012-10-21  0
1   2012-10-22  0
1   2012-10-23  0
1   2012-10-24  1
1   2012-10-25  0
1   2012-10-26  0
1   2012-10-27  0
1   2012-10-28  1
2   2012-10-19  0
2   2012-10-20  0
2   2012-10-21  0
2   2012-10-22  1
2   2012-10-23  1

scenario1:
1   2012-10-23  0
1   2012-10-24  1
1   2012-10-25  0

Scenario2:
1   2012-10-20  0
1   2012-10-21  0
1   2012-10-22  0
2   2012-10-19  0
2   2012-10-20  0
2   2012-10-21  0

Scenario3 - none (no records)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the patterns as strings and then use string comparison.

At least part of the trick is that you want all rows in the pattern, so you need to construct all potential patterns where each row might appear:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             concat(lag(status), -2) over (partition by id order by date),
                    lag(status), -1) over (partition by id order by date),
                    status
                   ) as pat1,
             concat(lag(status), -1) over (partition by id order by date),
                    status,
                    lead(status), 1) over (partition by id order by date)
                   ) as pat2,
             concat(status,
                    lead(status), 1) over (partition by id order by date),
                    lead(status), 2) over (partition by id order by date)
                   ) as pat3
      from t
     ) t
where '010' in (pat1, pat2, pat3);
```